# How to implement NFTs on a substrate chain?

Tags: pallet, nft

I want to implement NFTs on a substrate chain. Could someone provide options/resources which can help me accomplish this?

Comment: you can check this module on Acala network https://github.com/AcalaNetwork/Acala/blob/master/modules/nft/src/lib.rs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a general overview and real life ecosystem examples have a look at the [polkadot wiki NFTs](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-nft). In addition, the [NFTs pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/nfts) and the  [Uniques pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/uniques) are definitely worth looking into!

Comment: I would recommend the new [NFTs pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/nfts) over Uniques.

Answer (score 3):

To the Daan's question I I would like to add:

- A tutorial from the Parity Blog [How we created 50K Unique NFTs for Polkadot Decoded 2022](https://www.parity.io/blog/how-we-created-50K-NFTs-for-Polkadot-Decoded-2022-in-one-month?utm_source=linkedin&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=50k%20nfts&utm_content=parity) .
- A project from the ecosystem, [RMRK](https://www.rmrk.app/): a set of NFT legos that give NFTs infinite extensibility, hosted on the Kusama blockchain
- A video tutorial from sub0 about [Build an NFT Marketplace in an Hour](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7BNn47lfrV0)