# Creator NFT Royalties on substrate-based blockchains possible?

Tags: ink, rust, nft

Coming over from the Ethereum ecosystem and haven't been able to find much information about integrating creator royalties into ERC721 contracts using rust or ink!. I know on Ethereum, the large marketplaces have royalty registry contracts that you can import and integrate in your ERC721 contract. Is this the way it is done on substrate-based blockchains as well(if so, could you point me in the direction of a few) or is there a different implementation, or none at all?

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to keep it technical. First, NFT's can be can be created through a pallet (native business logic of the chain) or a smart contract (EVM / ink!) on Substrate-based chains. Have a look at [this question](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6653/how-to-implement-nfts-on-a-substrate-chain/6664#6664).

To your question now. You can use the same Solidity contracts on for example Moonbeam (through the EVM-pallet). You can use the same logic but write it in [ink!](https://use.ink/) (through pallet-contracts). Or, maybe the logic that you need is already to be found in for example the NFTs-pallet ([ref](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7963/what-is-the-purpose-of-tips-in-the-nfts-pallet/7966#7966)).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am interested in pay_tips as a solution, though I am not sure how it works completely. Do you know if the tip is awarded to the creator every transfer? Is it voluntary for the buyer each time or is it only voluntary during the creation?

Comment: Make a separate question for it and I'll make sure it gets answered!

Comment: Just made the separate question, thanks. https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/8263/how-does-the-pay-tips-parameter-work-for-nfts