# How does the pay_tips parameter work for NFTs?

Tags: frame, nft

Who is it voluntary for? The buyer or the creator of the NFT?

Does the tip get awarded to the creator after every transfer?

Is it voluntary for the buyer each time or is it only voluntary during the creation of the NFT and the first transfer?

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/nfts/src/features/buy_sell.rs#L25

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with [`pay_tips`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/6f0f5a92739b92199b3345fc4a716211c8a8b46f/frame/nfts/src/lib.rs#L1712-L1727) dispatchable call there is a concept of a receiver and a sender. It is voluntary for this extrinsic to be called, meaning "paying tips" is not a required part of buying/selling an NFT in this pallet.

Additionally, the receiver is defined within `ItemTip` struct:

```rust
/// Information about the tip.
#[derive(Clone, Encode, Decode, Eq, PartialEq, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo, MaxEncodedLen)]
pub struct ItemTip<CollectionId, ItemId, AccountId, Amount> {
    /// The collection of the item.
    pub(super) collection: CollectionId,
    /// An item of which the tip is sent for.
    pub(super) item: ItemId,
    /// A sender of the tip.
    pub(super) receiver: AccountId,
    /// An amount the sender is willing to tip.
    pub(super) amount: Amount,
}
```

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/6f0f5a92739b92199b3345fc4a716211c8a8b46f/frame/nfts/src/types.rs#L182-L193

Notice how the receiver is associated with a collection and item id - the design decision here was to use `pay_tips` for a buyer to voluntarily pay the creator royalties:

> `pay_tips`: Pay tips, could be used for paying the creator royalties.

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/nfts#permissionless-dispatchables

There is work being done to create a coupled pallet that makes royalties a requirement of NFT sales. You can follow the work on this branch:

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/bg/nfts-royalty

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. Is there an estimated time frame for the coupled pallet  royalties a requirement of NFT sales?

Comment: It is actively being developed upon stay close.